# How to Handle onClick in Fragments

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

This is my first try on Fragments and I'm not able to handle android:onClick

I have a button inside my fragment XML like this

```
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/save_keywords_button"
        android:id="@+id/save_keywords"
        android:layout_marginTop="340dp"
        android:background="#FF2E7D32"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:typeface="normal"
        android:onClick="myLogic" />
```

I searched many results and can't get the exact solution to handle the onClick event.

My question is, How can I get the ID of my button and write the myLogic method. 
FindViewById() is not working in fragments and where should I write the method?
in fragment or in my activity?

Comment: Visit this link https://developer.android.com/tools/data-binding/guide.html#binding_events

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Better approach would be implementing `OnClickListener` to your fragment class and overriding `onCreateView` in your fragment where you assign the listener to your button.

By putting `onClick` attribute in your XML layout, your activity on load will look for the element in the activity, not in the fragment. This will throw exception.

I would suggest reading some fragment-activity hierarchy to understand when is it possible to access elements in your fragment.

```
public class StartFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener{

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_start, container, false);

    Button b = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.save_keywords);
    b.setOnClickListener(this);
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.save_keywords:

        ...

        break;
    }
}
}
```

Reference from: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091194/how-to-handle-button-clicks-using-the-xml-onclick-within-fragments)

Answer (score 3):

`android:onClick="myLogic"` will not call the method `myLogic` inside the fragment. Use `OnClickListener` instead to handle this type of events.

See these below references

[Best way to implement View.OnClickListener in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30082892/best-way-to-implement-view-onclicklistener-in-android)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html

Answer (score 1):

If you need to get view in fragmen you can do this `getView().findViewById(R.id.foo);` only after `onCreateView()` has been called. And if you specify `onClick` in xml, you do not need to code any linking to that method in your program, just implement that method in your activity.

Comment: As you said, I wrote a method "public void myLogic(View v)" in main Activity but I' getting this error when I click the button 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method myLogic(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'save_keywords'

Comment: @Uday we would need code of your fragment and activity to see what is wrong. It is a good idea to set onclick listener manually. If you will misspell your method name in code, it will not be called.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add method

```
public void myLogic(View v)
```

Comment: Added it in my mainActivity and got this error on hitting the button 

Could not find method myLogic(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'save_keywords'