# How do I properly implement View.OnClickListener and use it with a TextView?

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I am intending to assign a click listener to a `TextView`. First I implemented `View.OnClickListener` in `MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    ...
    TextView title = findViewById(R.id.title);
    title.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ...
        }
    });
}
```

Then I set `android:clickable="true"` on the `TextView`.

However, despite overriding the `onClick` mehtod, an error pops up saying:

> Class 'MainActivity' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'onClick(View)' in 'OnClickListener'

What can I do to dodge this error?

Comment: Removing the View.OnclickListener interface should work.

Comment: No, I've already read this.

Comment: Did you see this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/30142323/208273

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root of the issue is with your activity declaration and there are two ways to deal with it.

- Let your activity implement the `View.onClickListener` and you pass the activity to the textview's `setOnClickListener`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    ...
    TextView title = findViewById(R.id.title);
    title.setOnClickListener(this);

    TextView title2 = findViewById(R.id.textview2);
    title2.setOnClickListener(this);


   // implement the onClick method in your MainActivity class
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            switch(view.getId()){
               case R.id.TextView1 : //logic for textview1
                   break;

               case R.id.TextView2: // logic for textview2
                   break;
            }
        }
}
```

- Modify your Activity function declaration and create a a new instance of `View.OnClickListener` in `setOnClickListener` method.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ...
    TextView title = findViewById(R.id.title);
    title.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ...
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Regarding the first method, I would like to do it this way but the problem is I have more than one button to which I want to assign a click listener. Can you please clarify how to assign a different event listener for each button?

Comment: @WaisKamal check the answer now and passing the `clickListener` will be the same

Comment: @WaisKamal is your problem solved mate?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are implementing `View.OnClickListener` you can make minor changes to your code to work,

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
   {
        ...
        TextView title = findViewById(R.id.title);
        title.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    //Outside of onCreate()
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){ 
    
    //Your code here 
    
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `implements View.OnClickListener` from your class declaration.

Comment: When I remove it the app crashes on startup.

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding, once you implement an interface you have to override all its methods. So is either you remove the local declaration of the onClick inside the onCreate and override the methods from the interface you implemented.